# How to define a XACML Policy inside a XACML PolicySet

Tags: access-control, xacml, wso2-identity-server

In the past week I have been trying to define a `policy` inside a `policyset` of wso2IdendityServer 4.5.0 version.

1. I am able to create `policyset` using `policyset` editor of wso2IdentidyServer 4.5.0 also able add `policy` in that but the problem is in XML format.

My generated policyset look like this (sample policyset)

```
<PolicySet>
   <Target>
      ...
   </Target>
   <PolicyIdReference>simple1</PolicyIdReference>
</PolicySet>
```

**Issues**

If we see in `<PolicyIdReference>` tag, it's taking reference of policy "simple1". But, My requirement is instead of taking only reference name "simple1", it should substitute the complete policy here As I have seen in some of the example . Something like this:

```
<PolicySet>
   <Target>
   </Target>
   <PolicyIdReference>urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:2.0:example:policyid:3</PolicyIdReference>
   <Policy PolicyId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:2.0:example:policyid:2" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:rule-combining-algorithm:deny-overrides">
      <Description>
   Policy for any medical record in the
   http://www.med.example.com/schemas/record.xsd namespace
  </Description>
      <Target/>
      <Rule RuleId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:2.0:example:ruleid:1" Effect="Permit"/>
      <Rule RuleId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:2.0:example:ruleid:2" Effect="Permit"/>
      <Rule RuleId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:2.0:example:ruleid:4" Effect="Deny"/>
   </Policy>
</PolicySet>
```

As here we can see after  tag,its adding policy in policyset.

So My question is which version of wso2 IdentityServer create such types of policyset also what version of xacml schema version it uses?

Thanks and Regards 
    Deepali Singh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSO2 Identity Server policy set editor only allows for you to define policy set as policy id references. Therefore selected policy would be added as references. If you need to add completed policy inside the policy set,  you can do it using XML view editor. Basically you can edit the created policy set using XML view and add your policy in to it.  This would not effect to PDP run time.  Both options would work. **It is just a limitation in creating policy set from editor UI**. However i guess this would be improved to add completed policies from policy set editor UI in future.

Comment: Hi Asela, Thanks for your valuable reply. It helped me solve the problem. Hope to see more such type of valuable reply from your side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ALFA plugin for Eclipse as well as the Axiomatics Policy Administration Point to author fully-conformant XACML 3.0 policies and policies including the option to either reference policies / policy sets or embed them directly as you requested.

That said, it's probably a better practice to reference policies when it makes sense since it then makes policy lifecycle much simpler.